# How to tell typescript all possible combinations of {type:enum, [type: string]:value} are in my type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

simplest example I could think of:

```
interface text {
  type: "text";
  text: string;
}
interface integer {
  type: "integer";
  integer: number;
}
type Config = text | integer;

function appendToBody(config: Config) {
  if (!config[config.type]) return;
  document.body.append(config[config.type]);
}

function createConfig(type: "text" | "integer", value: string | number) {
  // how to let TS know that type and [type] will be matching?
  // TS naturally assumes { type: 'text', text: 5 } is possible, even though it isn't
  const config: Config = {
    type,
    [type]: value
  };
  appendToBody(config);
}
createConfig("text", "hello world");
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/6gtq8

Basically i'm using a pattern that extracts a value by asking for obj[obj.type].
This is useful for my real case because I can make a generic resolver that extracts the values I need depending on the type. it also has the advantage of not having to be emptied if the type changes, because it will be saved on a different [type], and you won't lose your old value if you change back.

I just can't figure out how to make typescript understand that all the possible combinations of type and [type] is covered by the "Config" type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's be clear that `integer` should have a key named `integer`, and not `number`, right?  Like this:

```
interface text {
    type: "text";
    text: string;
}
interface integer {
    type: "integer";
    integer: number; // right?
}
type Config = text | integer;

function appendToBody(config: Config) {
    if (!config[config.type]) return;
    document.body.append(config[config.type]);
}
```

Okay.

---

There are two type safety issues here with `createConfig()`... one is enforcing type safety for the *caller*, and the other is enforcing type safety in the *implementation*.  Right now the compiler is warning you inside the implementation that it can't verify that `{ type: type, [type]: value }` is a valid `Config`.  And right now it's correct to warn you that, because callers can do the following with no error:

```
createConfig("text", 5); // no error, oops!
```

There is no simple way to fix this for both the caller and the implementer.  Each side has its own issues.

---

To fix it for the caller, you could use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) like the following:

```
function createConfig(type: "text", value: string): void;
function createConfig(type: "integer", value: number): void;
function createConfig(type: string, value: any): void {
    // impl
}
```

This is simple to understand, but requires adding an overload for each constituent of the `Config` union.  You could alternatively use [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) types and a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function, as follows:

```
type Lookup<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;
type ConfigFor<T extends Config['type']> = Extract<Config, { type: T }>;
function createConfig<T extends Config['type']>(
    type: T,
    value: Lookup<ConfigFor<T>, T>
) {
  // impl
}
```

That is complicated but will automatically behave correctly assuming each element `C` of the `Config` union conforms to the constraint that the `type` property names the relevant key for the value property.

Either of those results in the following behavior for callers:

```
createConfig("text", 5); // error
createConfig("integer", 5); // okay

createConfig("text", "hello world"); // okay
createConfig("integer", "hello world"); // error
```

---

To fix it for the implementation, (which was your actual question), the compiler will still not be able to figure out that `config` is a valid `Config` even with the fixed call signatures.  For overloads, it's because the implementation signature is too loose to express the constraint, and overload implementations [do not currently do any control flow analysis based on the call signatures](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22609).  For the generic conditional type, it's because conditional types that depend on unresolved generic type parameters in them also [do not get narrowed via control flow analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21879).  So in both cases, the compiler is basically giving up on enforcing type safety of your correlated data types inside the implementation.  I've often [wished](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for some mechanism that would allow you to prompt the compiler to walk through union types via control flow analysis, but that's just a fantasy for now.

So, what can you do?  There are really only two ways forward here, as far as I can tell.  Either you use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions): leave your code as is, but just tell the compiler that you will be responsible for assuring type safety, as in:

```
const configAsserted = {
    type,
    [type]: value
} as any as Config;
appendToBody(configAsserted);
```

Or, you do extra manual checks at runtime which convince the compiler that what you're doing is safe, as in:

```
let configManual: Config;
if (type === "integer" && typeof value === "number") {
    configManual = { type: "integer", integer: value };
} else if (type === "text" && typeof value === "string") {
    configManual = { type: "text", text: value };
} else {
    throw new Error("YOU MESSED UP");
}
appendToBody(configManual);
```

Both ways work.  Assertions are less safe but scale better when you add constituents to `Config`.  Manual checking is safe, but it is redundant and you have to add code every time you add a constituent to `Config`.

---

So there are your options as I see them.  Personally I'd opt for the better-scaling solutions, like this:

```
type Lookup<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;
type ConfigFor<T extends Config['type']> = Extract<Config, { type: T }>;
function createConfig<T extends Config['type']>(
    type: T,
    value: Lookup<ConfigFor<T>, T>
) {
    const config = {
        type,
        [type]: value
    } as any as Config;
    appendToBody(config);
}
```

[Link to code in Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=interface%20text%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20%22text%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20text%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20integer%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20%22integer%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20integer%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Atype%20Config%20%3D%20text%20%7C%20integer%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20appendToBody(config%3A%20Config)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(!config%5Bconfig.type%5D)%20return%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20document.body.append(config%5Bconfig.type%5D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ConfigFor%3CT%20extends%20Config%5B'type'%5D%3E%20%3D%20Extract%3CConfig%2C%20%7B%20type%3A%20T%20%7D%3E%3B%0D%0Atype%20Lookup%3CT%2C%20K%3E%20%3D%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%20%3F%20T%5BK%5D%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createConfig%3CT%20extends%20Config%5B'type'%5D%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20Lookup%3CConfigFor%3CT%3E%2C%20T%3E%0D%0A)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20config%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Btype%5D%3A%20value%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20as%20any%20as%20Config%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20appendToBody(config)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AcreateConfig(%22text%22%2C%205)%3B%0D%0AcreateConfig(%22integer%22%2C%205)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AcreateConfig(%22text%22%2C%20%22hello%20world%22)%3B%0D%0AcreateConfig(%22integer%22%2C%20%22hello%20world%22)%3B)

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Awesome answer! You are of course right I meant Integer to be the key.
I tried playing around the playground to see what breaks where and noticed that the line.   
type ConfigFor<T extends Config['type']> = Extract<Config, { type: T }>


seem a bit redundant? First you assign T to extends all Config['type'] and then you assign type to be T. Wouldn't type ConfigFor<T> do exactly the same?

Comment: I don't understand what you think is redundant.  `type ConfigFor<T> = ...` is a type alias definition, so I can't leave out the right hand side.  `T` *extends* `Config['type']`; it is not necessarily *equal to* `Config['type']`.  You can pass in, for example, `"text"` for `T`.  The idea of `ConfigFor<T>` is to take the union type `Config` and pull out just the constituent of the union that has `{type: T}`.  It is discriminating a discriminated union at the type level.

Answer (score 0):

Let make your `type Config` flexible, force it accepts any type with `{type: string, [anything]: anything}` format.

```
type Config = text | integer | {type: string, [key: string]: any};
```

Comment: I already tried this and while it does make typescript shut up it also ruins any type checking :\

Comment: Like if you write a switch case for every type it no longer recognizes that case: 'integer' will have obj.integer as a property guaranteed. and therefore vs code doesn't offer code completion etc